# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install -n serverless-plugin-existing-s3"

Tags: dockerfile, serverless-plugins

I have Dockerfile with **python:3.7-buster** image testing to install some dependency like **serverless-plugin-existing-s3**

```
RUN npm install -n serverless-plugin-existing-s3
```

```
[2024-01-23T14:25:33.578Z] WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.24.0 
[2024-01-23T14:25:33.578Z] 0.855 npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we 
[2024-01-23T14:25:33.578Z] 0.855 npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. 
[2024-01-23T14:25:33.578Z] 0.856 npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9. 
[2024-01-23T14:25:33.578Z] 0.856 npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

[2024-01-23T14:25:33.578Z] code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE 
[2024-01-23T14:25:33.578Z] 2.157 npm ERR! The value "false" is invalid for option "readableHighWaterMark"

26 | >>> RUN npm install -n serverless-plugin-existing-s3 

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install -n serverless-plugin-existing-s3" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

script returned exit code 1
```

Trying to build a docker image locally

```
Sample: docker build . -t [tag] -f /path/to/Dockerfile
Actual: docker build . -t test -f test/Dockerfile
```

got the error above. The expectation is serverless-plugin-existing-s3 should be installed without issue.

Comment: Can you add fill Dockerfile?